# value not insert into database from the input error:undefined in phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am new to phonegap. i created database containing two table. It showing sql error undefined.I created another table using below code with few modification. that table working fine.but below code is not working.i am unable to find bug.what's the error in it.please help.

```
function insertVehicleData(tx)
{
    var db=window.openDatabase("FuelDatabase","1.0","FuelData",200000);
    db.transaction(vehicleDB,errorVDB,successVDB);
}

function vehicleDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  vehicledata (vhname TEXT, vmake   TEXT,vtype TEXT,currency TEXT)');

    var  vhname=document.getElementById('vhname').value;
    var vmake= document.getElementById('vmake').value;
    var  vtype=document.getElementById('vtype').value;
    var currency=document.getElementById('currency').value;

    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO vehicledata (vhname,vmake,vtype,currency) VALUES ('"+ vhname +"','"+ vmake +"' , "+ vtype+", '"+ currency +"')");

 }

 function errorVDB(tx,error)
 {
     alert("error not saved:"+error);
 }

 function successVDB()
 {
     alert("your data saved");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO vehicledata (vhname,vmake,vtype,currency) VALUES ('"+ vhname +"','"+ vmake +"' , "+ vtype+", '"+ currency +"')");
```

with this line:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO vehicledata (vhname,vmake,vtype,currency) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",[vhname,vmake,vtype,currency]);
```

The reasoning is that when inserting values there maybe items that need to be escaped or else they can "break" the statement. Doing it this way ensures that values are escaped properly.